# Set Visual as Material in a CustomEntry

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a custom Entry for hiding the underline.
But how i can also set visual as material?

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
    {
    }

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace SelfOrder.Droid
{
    class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            
          //  e.visu.Visual = "Material" as VisualElement;
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
```

If i will set Visual as Material inside my xml,unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should Add the [Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material/) NuGet package to your iOS and Android platform projects.

There are detailed steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) you can follow.

Then in the `MainActivity.cs`, initialize Material Visual by :

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

In your xaml, set `Visual="Material"`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             
             Visual="Material"
             
             x:Class="App470.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Entry Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In the custom renderer, you should use `MaterialEntryRenderer`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomMaterialEntryRenderer), new[] { typeof(VisualMarker.MaterialVisual) })]
namespace App470.Android
{
    public class CustomMaterialEntryRenderer : MaterialEntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomMaterialEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```